# PHP: Remove all tags that contain the given class or id

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I am in need of some help.  I have looked into regex, but have not yet completely understand it's implementation.  I am in need of a snippet that will remove all tags, and their children, if the parent contains the given classes or ids.

Example:

```
<?php

function remove_tag($find="",$html)
{
    # Remove multiple #IDs and classes at once

    # When given a string (separating objects with a comma)
    if (is_string($find))
    {
        $objects = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $find);
    } else if (is_array($find)) {
        $objects = $find;
    }

    foreach ($objects as $object)
    {
        # If ID
        if (substr($object,0,1) == '#')
        {
            # regex to remove an id
            # Ex: '<ANYTAG [any number of attributes] id='/"[any number of ids] NEEDLE [any number of ids]'/" [any number of attributes]>[anything]</ENDTAG [anything]>'

        }

        if (substr($object,0,1) == '.')
        {
            # remove a class
            # Ex: '<ANYTAG [any number of attributes] class='/"[any number of classes] NEEDLE [any number of classes]'/" [any number of attributes]>[anything]</ENDTAG [anything]>'
        }

        # somehow remove it from the $html variable?
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question, thank you for your time! :)

-Pat

Comment: If you parse HTML with regex he will come http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: As many people have proved to me, though I first disagreed, simple regexp is not reliable way of HTML parsing. There always will be glitches. So if this parsed code is user input, use http://htmlpurifier.org/.

Comment: Hmm... Do you want to remove the class or remove the element?
   So do you want <div class="classNumberOne classNumberTwo"></div>    to become <div class="classNumberTwo"></div> (by removing the class called classNumberOne)?
   Or do you want the element that has a given class, just to be hidden? 

Without having fully understood what you want to achieve, then I would probably do it in javaScript (if I have understood what you want). Something along the lines of getElementById and put the style    display:none; on it. Sorry if I misunderstood your question... I tried. :-)

Comment: Regex can absolutely be used reliably for simple HTML parsing tasks on well structured markup.  I'm rather tired of seeing the mindless "don't use regex for HTML" mantra.  Like anything else, it's just fine as long as you know its limitations and understand the potential issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, instead of regex, XPath to find all the elements in a document which you want to remove.

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) would seem like a good start to me.

You can use [`DOMNode::removeChild()`](http://php.net/manual/domnode.removechild.php) method to remove a child, and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php) class to evaluate an XPath, to obtain the nodes you need to remove.